# Show that $b_n=0$ for all $n$.

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

> Suppose that the power series $p(x)=\sum b_nx^n$ converges for $|x|\le 1$.Suppose that for some $\delta >0$, $p(x)=0$ for $|x|<\delta $.
>
> Show that $b_n=0$ for all $n$.

**My effort**:The series $p(x)=\sum b_nx^n$ represents an analytic function and the power series has uncountably many zeros since $p(x)=0$ in $B(0,\delta)$.

Hence $p(x)=0$ which in turn $\implies b_n=0$

Is the solution okay ?

#### I have some doubts as I have not used the hypotheses that $p(x)=\sum b_nx^n$ converges for $|x|\le 1$.Please help

Comment: All that matters is that the power series has a positive radius of convergence, which is necessary in order for $p$ to be analytic.

Comment: Please make the title more informative.

Comment: Why do we need positive radius of convergence?@florence@Did

Answer (score 1):

By hypothesis the power series is convergent $p(x)=\sum b_nx^n$ in $[-1,1]$ and therefore it has a positive radius of convergence. Hence $\displaystyle n! b_n=\frac{d^np(0)}{dx^n}$ for all $n\geq 0$.

Moreover you know that $p(x)=0$ for $|x|<\delta$ then $\frac{d^np(0)}{dx^n}=0$ for all $n\geq 0$, which implies that $b_n=0$.

Comment: Why do we need positive radius of convergence?

Comment: What happens if we take radius=0

Comment: If $p(x)$ is convergent only at $0$ and $p(0)=0$ then we could have that $b_n\not=0$ for $n>0$. Tale for example $\sum_{n\geq 1} n!x^n $.